# PHP: Find last occurence of string in array

Tags: php, arrays, search

I need to find the last found element of a specific value from an array. I giving an example in php of what I'm actually seeking for.

```
$Data = array(
    '0' => 'car',
    '1' => 'bike',
    '2' => 'bus',
    '3' => 'bike',
    '4' => 'boat'
 );

$key = array_search('bike', $Data) // it returns $key = 1 as result which the first element matched inside the array.
```

I want `$key = 3` which is the last matched element.

Any suggestion appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use `array_reverse` to reverse array.

```
$key = array_search('bike', array_reverse($Data,true));
```

It will return 3.

Comment: Well, is there any way to do this without reversing an array ?
And what if it is a multidimensional array.

Answer (score 2):

[PHP code demo](https://eval.in/763201)

```
<?php
ini_set("display_errors", 1);
$Data = array(
    '0' => 'car',
    '1' => 'bike',
    '2' => 'bus',
    '3' => 'bike',
    '4' => 'boat'
 );
$toSearch="bike";
$index=null;
while($key=array_search($toSearch, $Data))
{
    $index=$key;
    unset($Data[$key]);
}
echo $index;
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is the more simple and highly performace way. For it only calculate once, you can access it many time. The [live demo](https://eval.in/763212).

```
$data = array_flip($Data);
echo $data['bike'];
```

after the flip, only keep the last element of the same elements. Here is the `print_r($data)`

```
Array
(
    [car] => 0
    [bike] => 3
    [bus] => 2
    [boat] => 4
)
```

Answer (score 1):

you can use `krsort` to sort the array by key.

```
 krsort($Data);
 $key = array_search('bike', $Data);
 echo $key;
```

Working example: https://3v4l.org/fYOgN

Answer (score 1):

For this I am created one function it is very easy to use. You can pass only array and parameters.

```
function text_to_id($value, $arr_master) {
    $id_selected = 0;
    $search_array = $arr_master;
    if (in_array($value, $search_array)) {
        $id_selected = array_search($value, $search_array);
        // pr($id_selected);exit;
    }

    if (!$id_selected) {
        foreach ($search_array as $f_key => $f_value) {
            if (is_array($f_value)) {
                if (in_array($value, $f_value)) {
                    $id_selected = $f_key;
                    break;
                }
            } else if ($value == $f_value) {
                $id_selected = $f_key;
                break;
            } 
                else;
        }
    }
    return $id_selected;
}
```

this function use like this 
  `$variable = text_to_id('bike', $your_array);`