# Get the last occurring subarray containing a qualifying column value

Tags: php, arrays, foreach, filtering

In PHP they have non-integer indexes to access arrays. So you must iterate over an array using a foreach loop. This becomes problematic when you need to take some decision.

For example this array sample

```
"result": [
    {
      "timeStamp": "1622101761",
      "value": "468538",
    },
    {
      "timeStamp": "1622111811",
      "value": "3489422753882542",
    },
    {
      "timeStamp": "1622111814",
      "value": "468538",
    },
    {
      "timeStamp": "1622111816",
      "value": "28381635",
    }
]
```

I need to find the last array with condition value "468538" and must be the last item of array, how could I do this?
Already create this code but no luck

```
  foreach ($array as $key => $value) {
      if (!next($array )) {
        if ($value['value']=="468538") {
          // last element with value 468538
          echo '<pre>';
          print_r($key);
          echo '</pre>';
          echo '<pre>';
          print_r($value);
          echo '</pre>';
        }
      } else {
          // not last element
      }
  }
```

but it show nothing, I need it to show it as a result

```
Array
(
    [timeStamp] => 1622111814
    [value] => 468538
)
```

Comment: _"In PHP they have non-integer indexes to access arrays"_... that's generally correct but in the case of your `result` array parsed from JSON, it will be numerically indexed so you can safely iterate backwards. And you can always use `array_values()` to produce a numerically indexed array

Comment: If you want to find the last element that meets a condition, use `foreach(array_reverse($array) as $value)` and break out of the loop when you find the match.

Comment: And if you want the last element of the array, use `end($array)`

Comment: ... which would work well when combined with `array_filter()`

Comment: What do you mean by _"and must be the last item of array"_? Do you mean that for the search value `468538` there should be no result because it's not the last array item?

Comment: Your question is very confusing. You say it should show that element, but it's not the last element of the array. Do you mean the last element that has `value=>468538`?

Comment: Related content for a flat array: [How do I find last occurence of "needle" in array php](https://stackoverflow.com/q/21223286/2943403)

Comment: Another flat array implementation of this same task: [PHP: Find last occurence of string in array](https://stackoverflow.com/q/43084591/2943403)  And here is the same task that searches the 3rd level of a multidimensional array: [How can I find the key of the last occurrence of an item in a multidimensional array?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/25046022/2943403)

Comment: @TheNewCoder Can you help me to understand why you chose an answer that makes multiple loops to find the latest qualifying subset?  Absolutely blowing my mind.  What do you find to be "best" about that advised snippet?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `result` array you're looping over is a numerically indexed array (JSON arrays are always indexed, JSON uses objects for associative arrays), so you don't have to worry about about non-numeric indexes.

Use `array_search()`, `array_column()`, and `array_reverse()` to find the index of the last element of the array with `value = 468538`.

Then when you're iterating over the array, you can check if this is the current index.

```
$special_index = count($array) - array_search("468538", array_reverse(array_column($array, "value"))) - 1;

foreach ($array as $i => $value) {
    if ($i === $special_index) {
        // do stuff for the special element
    } else {
        // do stuff for other elements
    }
}
```

Comment: Yeah, after I posted I'm not sure this is right, since they have an `else` that does other stuff for other elements of the array.

Comment: This answer is using an unnecessary amount of iteration/cycles.

Answer (score 1):

Here is one approach to solve it. This is bringing in your data as an array named `$haystack` and you provide a value for `$needle`. I'm outputting it as JSON and letting PHP handle the formatting since hand formatting as you have done in your example probably isn't what you really need. This also includes a check just in case you're looking for a value that does not exist.

```
$needle = "468538";
$needleLocation = -1;

for ($i = 0; $i < count($haystack); $i++) {
    if($haystack[$i]['value']==$needle) $needleLocation=$i;

}

if($needleLocation != -1){
    echo json_encode($haystack[$needleLocation]);
}
else{
    echo $needle . " is not found in the haystack";
}
```

Gives a result of:

```
{"timeStamp":"1622111814","value":"468538"}
```

Comment: Using a classic loop from the front of the array is not optimal (explained in my answer).

Answer (score 1):

You might enjoy the brevity of a functional-style iterator. Use `array_column()` to assign new first level keys. This will overwrite earlier keyed rows with later keyed rows, then you can merely access the sought row values by the new key.  If it doesn't exist in the new array, fall back to `null`.

Code: ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/hf7vt))

```
var_export(
    array_column($array['result'], null, 'value')[468538] ?? null
);
```

---

More pedestrian and most efficient would be a breakable loop that starts from the end of your array. [Demo](https://3v4l.org/IgQQQ)

```
$search = '468538';
$found = null;
for ($i = array_key_last($array['result']); $i >= 0; --$i) {
    if ($array['result'][$i]['value'] == $search) {
        $found = $array['result'][$i];
        break;  // stop looping after first match is found
    }
}
var_export($found);
```

---

Both of these approaches make at most, one cycle over the input.  You should certainly not entertain any approaches that need to iterate over the data more than once (that includes multiple functional iterators like `array_search()`, `array_reverse()`, and `array_column()`).

---

If you are going to iterate over all of the items in your array from the beginning and take conditional actions, then you should save the first level index (instead of the full subarray) as the `$found` variable [like this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77191670/2943403).  Then you merely compare first level keys while iterating.

```
foreach ($array as $i => $row) {
    if ($i === $found) {
        // do something
    } else {
        // do something else
    }
}
```

My advice remains that there is no reason to perform more than one loop to locate the latest qualifying subset.

Comment: Of course, going backward makes so much more sense!